# Video display window in OpenCV not sizing up to video

Tags: c++, opencv, codeblocks

I have written the following code below to display a video in OpenCV. I have compiled it fine but when I run it, the window that is supposed to show the video opens but it is too small to actually see if the video is playing. Everything else seems to be working fine. The width, height and number of frames are printed on the command line as coded. Anyone know what the problem is? Check it out.

```
void info()
{
   cout << "This program will accept input video with fixed lengths and produce video textures" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  info();
  if(argc != 2)
  {
    cout << "Please enter more parameters" << endl;
    return -1;

  }

const string source = argv[1];

VideoCapture input_vid(source);
if(! input_vid.isOpened())
{
    cout << "Error: Could not find input video file" << source << endl;
    return -1;
}


Size S = Size((int) input_vid.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH),    //Acquire size of input video
              (int) input_vid.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));

cout << "Width: = " << S.width << " Height: = " << S.height << " Number of frames: " << input_vid.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)<<endl;

const char* PLAY = "Video player";

namedWindow(PLAY, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
//imshow(PLAY,100);
char c;
c = (char)cvWaitKey(27);
//if ( c == 27)break;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming video is from webcam:

```
capture = CaptureFromCAM( 0 );
SetCaptureProperty(capture,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 640);
SetCaptureProperty(capture,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 480);
```

this will fix your problem

Comment: CaptureFromAvi i think it is?

Comment: yes, i wrote i assume if the capture is from cam. if AVI use CaptureFromAvi, im not so sure about this function. the above code's last two lines are required. let me know if you face other problems.

Comment: this is the only way round. change the dimensions as required

Answer (score 0):

another simple tweak could be using  CV_WINDOW_NORMAL instead of CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE

```
namedWindow(PLAY, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
```

which lets you resize the window manually

Comment: That doesn't work :( Whilst the program is running, my mouse is inactive so can't set the video size to actually see the video